# How am I meant to use Filepath.Walk in Go?

Tags: closures, go

The `filepath.Walk` function takes a function callback. This is straight function with no context pointer. Surely a major use case for `Walk` is to walk a directory and take some action based on it, with reference to a wider context (e.g. entering each file into a table).

If I were writing this in C# I would use an object (with fields that could point back to the objects in the context) as a callback (with a given callback method) on it so the object can encapsulate the context that `Walk` is called from.

(EDIT: user "[usr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122718/usr)" suggests that the closure method occurs in C# too)

If I were writing this in C I'd ask for a function and a context pointer as a `void *` so the function has a context pointer that it can pass into the `Walk` function and get that passed through to the callback function.

But Go only has the function argument and no obvious context pointer argument.

(If I'd designed this function I would have taken an object as a callback rather than a function, conforming to the interface `FileWalkerCallback` or whatever, and put a `callback(...)` method on that interface. The consumer could then attach whatever context to the object before passing it to `Walk`.)

The only way I can think of doing it is by capturing the closure of the outer function in the callback function. Here is how I am using it:

```
func ScanAllFiles(location string, myStorageThing *StorageThing) (err error) {
    numScanned = 0

    // Wrap this up in this function's closure to capture the `corpus` binding.
    var scan = func(path string, fileInfo os.FileInfo, inpErr error) (err error) {
        numScanned ++

        myStorageThing.DoSomething(path)
    }

    fmt.Println("Scan All")

    err = filepath.Walk(location, scan)

    fmt.Println("Total scanned", numScanned)

    return
}
```

In this example I create the callback function so its closure contains the variables `numScanned` and `myStorageThing`.

This feels wrong to me. Am I right to think it feels weird, or am I just getting used to writing Go? How is it intended for the `filepath.Walk` method to be used in such a way that the callback has a reference to a wider context?

Comment: If you want to get almost an instant reply on issues like this regarding Go idioms, you should post it on the golang group where the dev team and contributors are extremely active: http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts . They are a fantastic support.

Comment: Not instant. I have a solution. It's more of a 'best practice' kind of thing. I might post on the google group, but something tells me I'll need a google account...

Comment: You do need a google account. But you also will get a reply pretty fast. Its a very active group.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're doing it about right.  There are two little variations you might consider.  One is that you can replace the name of an unused parameter with an underbar.  So, in your example where you only used the path, the signature could read

```
func(path string, _ os.FileInfo, _ error) error
```

It saves a little typing, cleans up the code a little, and makes it clear that you are not using the parameter.  Also, for small functions especially, it's common skip assigning the function literal to a variable, and just use it directly as the argument.  Your code ends up reading,

```
err = filepath.Walk(location, func(path string, _ os.FileInfo, _ error) error {
    numScanned ++

    myStorageThing.DoSomething(path)
})
```

This cleans up scoping a little, making it clear that you are using the closure just once.

Comment: Nice! reminiscent of JavasScript (not sure if that's a good thing or not). Thank you.

Comment: `return nil` seems to be missing

Answer (score 0):

As a C# programmer I can say that this is exactly how such an API in .NET would be *meant* to be used. You would be encouraged to use closures and discouraged to create an explicit class with fields because it just wastes your time.

As Go supports closures I'd say this is the right way to use this API. I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: It's been a long time since I wrote C# (well, 3 years), but I remember  using the 'pass a callback object' quite a lot, if only for unit testing purposes. But I suppose different tasks call for different styles.

Comment: I guess three years ago closures where still new to C#.